# Windows Server 2008 R2 Administrator Access Rights Removed

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions

I accidentally removed the builtin/local Administrator on Security tab of one of the drive's Properties. I did changing the UAC: User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode to Disabled. I can click the Edit button on the Security Tab of the drive's Properties. However, when I try to click Apply, it says Access is denied. Is there any way I can add the builtin/local Administrator again? Need help on this. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Open cmd.exe as an elevated administrator and type:

`takeown /F E:\`

this gives the ownership of the E drive back to the current user. As soon as you are the owner, you can set permissions again, even if you don't have any rights to do so.

You may need to run the recursively, check:

`takeown /?`